# Installation issue with Qt Quick Components for Desktop to use with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

I have some installation issues with the Qt Quick Components for Desktop.

Any help to resolve the issue is appreciated.

Following are the steps I have followed

1. Downloaded the tar.gz from
   http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/trees/master Unpacked
   the components
2. Added path variable value to the environment variables (OS : Windows 7) C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin
3. Ran the following command: qmake && mingw-make install This command
       has automatically copied the compiled component files to
       C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\imports\QtDesktop

Now when am going to the creator. In the design tab I can see the desktop components.
But its giving following error
[image]

I have also refered various links in to get them installed but still am facing the same issue

Comment: I clearly says that it is expecting styleplugin for this QtDesktop component to work. Actually the styleplugin is used for all types of components such as Symbian, Android, Blackberry to provide the native look and feel.